# Unable to uninstall a component after doing a minor upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installation, upgrade, uninstallation

I have two applications that share an msi. Lets call them A and B. I installed A first. Then when I install B[which has a higher version of the shared msi] a minor upgrade happens. Now I uninstalled A.The shared msi components remains,it is not uninstalled[This is the expected behavior]. Then I uninstalled B. Now the contents of the shared msi still remain in the program files folder. In the log for un installation, it is said that the product was removed successfully. But the components of the shared msi still remain.
How to uninstall the shared msi components when uninstalling the both the products?

Comment: Check those specific files and see if you have marked them as *Permanent* ? Marking a file as permanent will not remove the file during a uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is confusing for a few reasons. Applications don't share an MSI, not sure what that means. It's also not clear that you actually did a minor upgrade. It is only a minor upgrade if you increase the MSI version, increase the file versions of those files you want upgrading, use the same ProductCode as the original, install it with a command line that includes REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus, and ensure the component ids in both old and new MSI files are identical for identical items (files, registry data). If you didn't do these things you may simply have another MSI that happens to install some files over an already installed product in a haphazard way. Uninstalls in these situations can lead to unpredictable results. In addition, files will stay behind if they were ever explicitly marked permanent or shared legacy, and your question isn't tagged with the tool you used so I can't say what these would be called in your situation. The short answer is that there are many ways to get the issue you're having but there's not enough info there to say what the problem might be.